# Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I started https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step series. I stopped on the lesson **Vue, Laravel, and AJAX** with this error:

> vue.js:2574 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "list" (found in component )

I have this code in **main.js**

```vue
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    created() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
    }
});
new Vue({
    el: '.container'
})
```

I know that the problem is in **created()** when I overwrite the list prop, but I am a newbie in Vue, so I totally don't know how to fix it. Does anyone know how (and please explain why) to fix it?

Comment: Guess, It is a just a warning message and not an error.

Comment: you need to create a data structure with a variable that will hold the result of the JSON.parse result: `date() { return {val: null}}` and in the created part, your should assign the value `created() {this.val = JSON.parse(this.list)}`

Comment: As an important detail, the course is based on Vue 1.0 hence quite old and the author of the course probably couldn't know the best practices at that time, quite a few things have changed in between (we're running Vue3 as of today for example).

Answer (score 376, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that *[mutating a prop locally is considered an anti-pattern in Vue 2](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html)*

What you should do now, in case you want to *mutate a prop locally*, is to declare a field in your `data` that uses the `props` value as its initial value and then mutate the copy:

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            mutableList: JSON.parse(this.list);
        }
    }
});
```

You can read more about this on [Vue.js official guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

---

**Note 1:** Please note that *[you should **not** use the same name for your `prop` and `data`](http://forum.vuejs.org/t/questions-regarding-handling-immutable-props-and-mutable-data-props/967/2?u=iraklisg)*, i.e.:

```
data: function () { return { list: JSON.parse(this.list) } } // WRONG!!
```

**Note 2:** Since [I feel there is some confusion](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/update-data-when-prop-changes-data-derived-from-prop/1517) regarding `props` and *reactivity*, I suggest you to have a look on [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/pull/862) thread

Comment: This is a great answer, but I also think that it should be updated to include event binding. An event triggered from the child can update the parent, which will pass updated props to the child. That way, the source of truth is still maintained across all components.

It may also be worth mentioning Vuex for managing state that is shared across multiple components.

Comment: @WesHarper, it is also possible to use the [.sync modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) as a shorthand to automatically get the parent's update event.

Comment: @danb4r `.sync` was deprecated and is [nowadays removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html).

Comment: Good thing to know here, is that `mutableList` will be static and not be reactive if there are some updates towards `list` (behavior of `data()`). A `computed()` could be a nice solution to solve that one. Also, is this solution doing a deepClone?

Answer (score 118):

The Vue pattern is `props` down and `events` up.  It sounds simple, but is easy to forget when writing a custom component.

As of Vue 2.2.0 you can use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components) (with [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)).  I have found this combination creates a simple, clean, and consistent interface between components:

- Any `props` passed to your component remains reactive (i.e., it's not cloned nor does it require a `watch` function to update a local copy when changes are detected).
- Changes are automatically emitted to the parent.
- Can be used with multiple levels of components.

A computed property permits the setter and getter to be separately defined.  This allows the `Task` component to be rewritten as follows:

```
Vue.component('Task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    model: {
        prop: 'list',
        event: 'listchange'
    },
    computed: {
        listLocal: {
            get: function() {
                return this.list
            },
            set: function(value) {
                this.$emit('listchange', value)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The [model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#model) property defines which `prop` is associated with `v-model`, and which event will be emitted on changes.  You can then call this component from the parent as follows:

```
<Task v-model="parentList"></Task>
```

The `listLocal` computed property provides a simple getter and setter interface within the component (think of it like being a private variable).  Within `#task-template` you can render `listLocal` and it will remain reactive (i.e., if `parentList` changes it will update the `Task` component).  You can also mutate `listLocal` by calling the setter (e.g., `this.listLocal = newList`) and it will emit the change to the parent.

What's great about this pattern is that you can pass `listLocal` to a child component of `Task` (using `v-model`), and changes from the child component will propagate to the top level component.

For example, say we have a separate `EditTask` component for doing some type of modification to the task data.  By using the same `v-model` and computed properties pattern we can pass `listLocal` to the component (using `v-model`):

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="task-template">
    <div>
        <EditTask v-model="listLocal"></EditTask>
    </div>
</script>
```

If `EditTask` emits a change it will appropriately call `set()` on `listLocal` and thereby propagate the event to the top level.  Similarly, the `EditTask` component could also call other child components (such as form elements) using `v-model`.

Comment: I'm doing something similar except with sync. Problem is I need to run another method after emitting my change event, however when the method runs and hits the getter, I get the old value because the change event hasn't yet been picked up by the listener / propagated back to the child. This is a case where I want to mutate the prop so my local data is correct until the parent update propagates back down. Any thoughts in this regard?

Comment: I suspect calling the getter from the setter isn't good practice.  What you might consider is putting a watch on your computed property and adding your logic there.

Comment: props down and events up is what clicked with me. Where is this explained in VueJs' docs?

Comment: @nebulousGirl Have a look here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: I think this is the more painless way of emitting the changes to parent component.

Comment: how about if we have one more model/props ?, how to put here model: {
        prop: 'list',
        event: 'listchange'
    },

Answer (score 46):

Vue just warns you: you change the prop in the component, but when parent component re-renders, "list" will be overwritten and you lose all your changes. So it is dangerous to do so.

Use computed property instead like this:

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    computed: {
        listJson: function(){
            return JSON.parse(this.list);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What about a 2 way binding prop?

Comment: If you want 2 way data binding you should use custom events, for more info read: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier
You still can't modify directly the prop, you need an event and function which handles a prop change for you.

Comment: link seems to be outdated, try this one: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events#sync-Modifier

Answer (score 30):

If you're using Lodash, you can clone the prop before returning it. This pattern is helpful if you modify that prop on both the parent and child.

Let's say we have prop *list* on component *grid*.

**In Parent Component**

```html
<grid :list.sync="list"></grid>
```

**In Child Component**

```
props: ['list'],
methods:{
    doSomethingOnClick(entry){
        let modifiedList = _.clone(this.list)
        modifiedList = _.uniq(modifiedList) // Removes duplicates
        this.$emit('update:list', modifiedList)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using [Lodash's `cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) before too, but now that we do have [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), that one may not be needed anymore. It's also faster in terms of execution. Still, always better than `JSON.parse/stringify`.

Answer (score 25):

Props down, events up. That's Vue's Pattern. The point is that if you try to mutate props passing from a parent. It won't work and it just gets overwritten repeatedly by the parent component. Child component can only emit an event to notify parent component to do sth. If you don't like these restrict, you can use VUEX(actually this pattern will suck in complex components structure, you should use VUEX!)

Comment: There's also an option to use event bus

Comment: event bus is not natively supported in vue 3. https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/118

Comment: Even if it is, it's always kinda dodgy because it's an in-between but without the Vue devtools. I'm not sure about the actual benefits of it. The Singleton Composable pattern also exist, it's cleaner and far better but it does have the same drawbacks regarding the devtools.

Answer (score 20):

You should not change the props's value in child component.
If you really need to change it you can use `.sync`.
Just like this

`<your-component :list.sync="list"></your-component>`

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    created() {
        this.$emit('update:list', JSON.parse(this.list))
    }
});
new Vue({
    el: '.container'
})
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the VueJs 2.0, you should not mutate a prop inside the component. They are only mutated by their parents. Therefore, you should define variables in data with different names and keep them updated by watching actual props.
In case the list prop is changed by a parent, you can parse it and assign it to mutableList. Here is a complete solution.

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: ´<ul>
                  <li v-for="item in mutableList">
                      {{item.name}}
                  </li>
              </ul>´,
    props: ['list'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            mutableList = JSON.parse(this.list);
        }
    },
    watch:{
        list: function(){
            this.mutableList = JSON.parse(this.list);
        }
    }
});
```

It uses mutableList to render your template, thus you keep your list prop safe in the component.

Comment: is not watch expensive to be used?

Comment: @KickButtowski depends on what you watch. It can be done well.

Answer (score 9):

do not change the props directly in components.if you need change it set a new property like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    listClone: this.list
  }
}
```

And change the value of listClone.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is simple, you should break the direct prop mutation by assigning the value to some local component variables(could be data property, computed with getters, setters, or watchers).

Here's a simple solution using the watcher.

```html
<template>
  <input
    v-model="input"
    @input="updateInput" 
    @change="updateInput"
  />

</template>

<script>
  export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      input: '',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(after) {
        this.input = after;
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput() {
      this.$emit('input', this.input);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

It's what I use to create any data input components and it works just fine. Any new data sent(v-model(ed)) from parent will be watched by the value watcher and is assigned to the input variable and once the input is received, we can catch that action and emit input to parent suggesting that data is input from the form element.

Comment: Using word 'input' for data.input IMHO makes it confusing when it collides with @input event. Technically when looking from inside of the child perspective it is going to be output. And when parent subscribes to it is "input" from child. Better would be call it `data.name` or smth clear and not dependent on perspective and not colliding name with events

Comment: @DimitryK This is THE problem with `v-model`. Apparently, folks have lost their minds and actively promote using v-model on ANY component, regardless of whether that  component has anything whatsoever to do with user input.  Vuetify does this to spectacular negative effect on their `v-dialog` and `v-bottom-sheet` components.  Listening for `@input` on a dialog  or bottom sheet borders on insanity, as neither component accepts input of any type - and coding them as if they did is a serious anti-pattern.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue as well. The warning gone after i use `$on` and `$emit`.
It's something like use `$on` and `$emit` recommended to sent data from child component to parent component.

Answer (score 6):

Vue3 has a really good solution. Spent hours to reach there. But it worked really good.

On parent template

```html
<user-name
  v-model:first-name="firstName"
  v-model:last-name="lastName"
></user-name>
```

The child component

```
app.component('user-name', {
      props: {
      firstName: String,
      lastName: String
     },
template: `
   <input 
  type="text"
  :value="firstName"
  @input="$emit('update:firstName', 
 $event.target.value)">

<input
  type="text"
  :value="lastName"
   @input="$emit('update:lastName', 
    $event.target.value)">
  `
})
```

This was the only solution which did two way binding. I like that first two answers were addressing in good way to use SYNC and Emitting update events, and compute property getter setter, but that was heck of a Job to do and I did not like to work so hard.

Comment: Forwarding the event to the parent, and NOT MAKING A COPY, is in the true spirit of Vue.  This is by far the best solution;  The accepted answer of making a second copy in the child should be a LAST RESORT.  By the way, this approach works on both Vue2 and Vue3.

Answer (score 5):

one-way Data Flow,
according to  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html, the component follow one-Way
Data Flow,
All props form a one-way-down binding  between the child property and the parent one, when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child but not the other way around, this prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent's, which can make your app's data flow harder to understand.

In addition, every time the parent component is updates all props
in  the child components will be refreshed with the latest value. This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component. If you do .vue will warn you in the
console.

There are usually two cases where it’s tempting to mutate a prop:
The prop is used to pass in an initial value; the child component wants to use it as a local data property afterwards.
The prop is passed in as a raw value that needs to be transformed.
The proper answer to these use cases are:
Define a local data property that uses the prop’s initial value as its initial value:

```
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
  return { counter: this.initialCounter }
}
```

Define a computed property that is computed from the prop’s value:

```
props: ['size'],
computed: {
  normalizedSize: function () {
    return this.size.trim().toLowerCase()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I want to give this answer which helps avoid using a lot of code, watchers and computed properties. In some cases this can be a good solution:

Props are designed to provide one-way communication.

When you have a modal `show/hide` button with a prop the best solution to me is to emit an event:

```html
<button @click="$emit('close')">Close Modal</button>
```

Then add listener to modal element:

```html
<modal :show="show" @close="show = false"></modal>
```

(In this case the prop `show` is probably unnecessary because you can use an easy `v-if="show"` directly on the base-modal)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to mutate props - use object.

```html
<component :model="global.price"></component>
```

component:

```
props: ['model'],
methods: {
  changeValue: function() {
    this.model.value = "new value";
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, you have to be careful when mutating objects. Javascript objects are passed by reference, but there is a caveat: The reference is broken when you set a variable **equal to** a value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add computed method like this

**component.vue**

```
props: ['list'],
computed: {
    listJson: function(){
        return JSON.parse(this.list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    computed: {
      middleData() {
        return this.list
      }
    },
    watch: {
      list(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal)
        this.newList = newVal
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        newList: {}
      }
    }
});
new Vue({
    el: '.container'
})
```

Maybe this will meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Vue.js props are not to be mutated as this is considered an Anti-Pattern in Vue.

The approach you will need to take is creating a data property on your component that references the original *prop* property of *list*

```
props: ['list'],
data: () {
  return {
    parsedList: JSON.parse(this.list)
  }
}
```

Now your list structure that is passed to the component is referenced and mutated via the `data` property of your component :-)

If you wish to do more than just parse your list property then make use of the Vue component' `computed` property.
This allow you to make more in depth mutations to your props.

```
props: ['list'],
computed: {
  filteredJSONList: () => {
    let parsedList = JSON.parse(this.list)
    let filteredList = parsedList.filter(listItem => listItem.active)
    console.log(filteredList)
    return filteredList
  }
}
```

The example above parses your *list* prop and filters it down to only **active** list-tems, logs it out **for schnitts and giggles** and returns it.

*note*: both `data` & `computed` properties are referenced in the template the same e.g

```
<pre>{{parsedList}}</pre>

<pre>{{filteredJSONList}}</pre>
```

It can be easy to think that a `computed` property (being a method) needs to be called... it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

For when TypeScript is your preferred lang. of development

```
<template>
<span class="someClassName">
      {{feesInLocale}}
</span>
</template>  



@Prop({default: 0}) fees: any;

// computed are declared with get before a function
get feesInLocale() {
    return this.fees;
}
```

and not

```
<template>
<span class="someClassName">
      {{feesInLocale}}
</span>
</template>  



@Prop() fees: any = 0;
get feesInLocale() {
    return this.fees;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the best answer,

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: ['list'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            mutableList: JSON.parse(this.list);
        }
    }
});
```

Setting props by an array is meant for dev/prototyping, in production make sure to set prop types(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) and set a default value in case the prop has not been populated by the parent, as so.

```
Vue.component('task', {
    template: '#task-template',
    props: {
      list: {
        type: String,
        default() {
          return '{}'
        }
      }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            mutableList: JSON.parse(this.list);
        }
    }
});
```

This way you atleast get an empty object in `mutableList` instead of a JSON.parse error if it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the props to new variable.

```js
data () {
    return {
        listClone: this.list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YES!, mutating attributes in vue2 is an anti-pattern. BUT...
Just break the rules by using other rules, and go forward!
What you need is to add `.sync` modifier to your component attribute in the parent scope.

```html
<your-awesome-components :custom-attribute-as-prob.sync="value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a snack bar component, when I give the **snackbar** variable directly into v-model like this if will work but in the console, it will give an error as

**Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.**

```html
<template>
        <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar">
        {{ text }}
      </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "loader",
     
        props: {
            snackbar: {type: Boolean, required: true},
            text: {type: String, required: false, default: ""},
        },
      
    }
</script>
```

Correct Way to get rid of this mutation error is use **watcher**

```html
<template>
        <v-snackbar v-model="snackbarData">
        {{ text }}
      </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable */ 
    export default {
        name: "loader",
         data: () => ({
          snackbarData:false,
        }),
        props: {
            snackbar: {type: Boolean, required: true},
            text: {type: String, required: false, default: ""},
        },
        watch: { 
        snackbar: function(newVal, oldVal) { 
          this.snackbarData=!this.snackbarDatanewVal;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

So in the main component where you will load this snack bar you can just do this code

```html
<loader :snackbar="snackbarFlag" :text="snackText"></loader>
```

**This Worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js considers this an anti-pattern. For example, declaring and setting some props like

```
this.propsVal = 'new Props Value'
```

So to solve this issue you have to take in a value from the props to the data or the computed property of a Vue instance, like this:

```
props: ['propsVal'],
data: function() {
   return {
       propVal: this.propsVal
   };
},
methods: {
...
}
```

This will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, for others having the following issue:

***"If the props value is not required and thus not always returned, the passed data would return `undefined` (instead of empty)". Which could mess `<select>` default value, I solved it by checking if the value is set in `beforeMount()` (and set it if not) as follows:***

***JS:***

```
export default {
        name: 'user_register',
        data: () => ({
            oldDobMonthMutated: this.oldDobMonth,
        }),
        props: [
            'oldDobMonth',
            'dobMonths', //Used for the select loop
        ],
        beforeMount() {
           if (!this.oldDobMonth) {
              this.oldDobMonthMutated = '';
           } else {
              this.oldDobMonthMutated = this.oldDobMonth
           }
        }
}
```

***Html:***

```
<select v-model="oldDobMonthMutated" id="dob_months" name="dob_month">

 <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">
 Select Month
 </option>

 <option v-for="dobMonth in dobMonths"
  :key="dobMonth.dob_month_slug"
  :value="dobMonth.dob_month_slug">
  {{ dobMonth.dob_month_name }}
 </option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally always suggest if you are in need to mutate the props, first pass them to computed property and return from there, thereafter one can mutate the props easily, even at that you can track the prop mutation , if those are being mutated from another component too or we can you watch also .

Answer (score 0):

Because Vue props is one way data flow, This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state.

From the official Vue document, we will find 2 ways to solve this problems

1. if child component want use props as local data, it is best to define a local data property.

   ```js
     props: ['list'],
     data: function() {
       return {
         localList: JSON.parse(this.list);
       }
     }
   ```
2. The prop is passed in as a raw value that needs to be transformed. In this case, it’s best to define a computed property using the prop’s value:

   ```js
     props: ['list'],
     computed: {
       localList: function() {
          return JSON.parse(this.list);
       },
       //eg: if you want to filter this list
       validList: function() {
          return this.list.filter(product => product.isValid === true)
       }
       //...whatever to transform the list
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid mutating props in vue, or any other framework. The approach you could take is copy it into another variable.

for example.
`// instead of replacing the value of this.list use a different variable`

`this.new_data_variable = JSON.parse(this.list)`

Answer (score -1):

A potential solution to this is using global variables.

```
import { Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

export const globalStore = new Vue({
  data: {
    list: [],
  },
}

export function setupGlobalsStore() {
  Vue.prototype.$globals = globalStore;
}
```

Then you would use:

```
$globals.list
```

Anywhere you need to mutate it or present it.

Comment: if you do it this way, then why are you using Vue. Globals should not be used for local variables.