# Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have very common problem with upgrading to Vue 2.0

I am getting warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "username"  (found in the component )

I read the documentation many times but I still can't understand how to fix it.

`username` and `password` are declared in the main Vue app.

Here is my code:

```
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
   props : ['username', 'password'],
      template: `
        <div id="auth">
            <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="UserName">User name</label>
                  <input type="username" v-model="username" class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>`,
    });
```

```
App = new Vue ({ 
   el: '#app',
  data: 
    {
      topMenuView: "guestmenu",
      contentView: "guestcontent",
      username: "",
      password: "",

    }
})
```

I tried `v-bind` but it does not seem to work, and I can't understand why. It should bind the value to parent (the main Vue app)

Comment: Please see this issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn
, should be able to help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn)

Answer (score 45):

From Vue 2.3.0 on you can use the `.sync` modifier:

Sample from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier:

```
<text-document :title.sync="title"></text-document>
```

and in your controller...

```
this.$emit('update:title', newTitle)
```

Answer (score 25):

You should make a computed property with a getter and setter and then use `$emit` to update the property, e.g:

```
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
    props: ['username', 'password'],
    template: `
    <div id="auth">
        <form class="form-inline pull-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="UserName">User name</label>
              <input type="username" v-model="usernameInput" class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" v-model="passwordInput" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>`,
    computed: {
        usernameInput: {
            get: function(){
                return this.username;
            },
            set: function(newValue){
                this.$emit('update:username', newValue)
            }   
        },
        passwordInput: {
            get: function(){
                return this.password;
            },
            set: function(newValue){
                this.$emit('update:password', newValue)
            }   
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add the .sync bit from the first answer.

Answer (score 12):

Vue.js consider this as anti-pattern. For example, declaring and setting some props like

```
this.propsVal = 'new Props Value'
```

So to solve this issue you have to take in value from the props to data or computed property of Vue instance. like...

```
props: ['propsVal'],
data: function() {
   return {
       propVal: this.propsVal
   };
},
methods: {
...
}
```

and you can use your props value like normally.

Comment: This does not work - I still get the error when I change this.propsVal

Comment: @Gerfried depends on the type of your variable. If you have an object/array, it won't work, because it is just a new reference. It only works for primitives like boolean, string and number. If you want to make it work, you have to clone the object. Eg. with lodash _.cloneDeep or using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObjectProp)).

Answer (score 5):

if you want to mutate props - use object.

```
<component :user="global.user"></component>
```

component:

```
    props: ['user'],
    methods: {
      setUser: function() {
        this.user.username= "User";
        this.user.password= "myPass123";
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should not use objects to "get around" this warning. You should instead not modify props at all, and instead assign them to a local mutable "data" property. If you need to modify global data, you should consider Vuex, but regardless of how you handle globals, you should not edit props.

Comment: I am using props to alias states from components into small component. I want to mutate props in this component. In terms of pure functions: I have many pure functions that can operate single impure function. I hate these vue rudiments from functional programming. React + MobX doesn't have this junk.

Comment: @DaveGoodchild You are 100% correct in reiterating the "party line" from vue.js docs/team e.g. visit [this guide] (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html) and search for "opinion" you'll see they sell vue as an "unopinionated" framework/library. Then all over the community / docs I see extreme "opinions" presented as hard "facts". I want my components to mutate props. I don't want the complexity of Vuex/boilerplate code emitting hundreds of events. But that's not the "opinion" of the vue team. At least they've taken "unopinionated" off their homepage.

Comment: There's plenty of ways to skin a cat, but in vue world there's only one !

Comment: e.g. I've seen the original creator of vue saying that there is never a use case for hidden fields in html forms !!!!! I beg to differ.

Comment: @DaveGoodchild FYI I +1 your comment as it usefully spreads a core concept of vue.js design/opinions i.e. one way data flow. My further comments are my opinion, your comment is "the vue opinion".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve but I'll take two options out of it.

First one: It's all about getting rid of this warning.

```
data () {
  return {
    childVal: this.parentVal
  }
}
```

Second one: You want to communicate between parent and child.

If I got it right, this is a basic example of an `<input>` in a child component communicating with its parent.

Parent HTML:

```
<p>{{ user }}</p>
<child-component v-model="user">
```

Parent JS:

```
data () {
  return {
    user: 'John'
  }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<input v-bind:value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
```

Child JS:

```
props: ['value']
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kf3aLr1u/

You can also read more about it in the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html.

Answer (score 2):

A `computed` property with appropriate `get` and `set` worked for me:

```
computed: {
  dialogDataProp: {
      get: function() {
        return this.dialog;
      },
      set: function() {}
    }
}
```

Code above for toggling a dialog box.

Comment: can you provide complete parent to child props event?  is this a child computed property ? how u setup your parent ?

Comment: So, it's `<v-dialog v-model="dialogDataProp">` I am using this as per [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#dialog) - and have `get` and `set` to control the toggling.

Comment: Sorry, also, there is `props: { dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }}` here, and 'parent' is passing in value for prop `:dialog`. But, we don't mutate that `prop` - we use the `computed` as shown.

Comment: i also use v-dialog of vuetify but when dialog box click outside and close the state of dialog not change to false.

Comment: thanks for response, now i its finally working i use set() to pass false value in parent and change dialog value to parent so that i can now toggle v-dialog using props

Answer (score 2):

**Fast solution if your prop is an object.**

You can avoid using `$emit` or getting that error by using `Object.assign()` in Javascript.
This is going to work the same as `v-model` attribute.

example:

```
// Update the user
Object.assign(this.userProp, user);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the emit, then:

```
<text-document :title.sync="title"></text-document>
```

to change the value is:

```
this.$emit('update:title', newTitle)
```

or another way:

```
this.$emit('update')
```

and you can get on the template:

```
<text-document :update="oneFunctionInMethods()"></text-document>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `v-bind` the property is bind using two directions, that is why you get the warning.

If you need to pass the initial username from the parent Vue component, you can use `v-bind` with another data property such as `_username` and copy the initial value from the property to the internal data when the component is created:

```
props : ['username', 'password'],
data () {
  return {
    _username: this.username,
    _password: this.password
  }
}
```

Edit: you can also use a $watch to update the _username / _password component data when the properties change.

Comment: Am I right understand that `this` in `this.username` is point to the parent?

Comment: `this` points to the properties username and password (current component), I don't understand the `unexpeced token :` error though

Comment: TiagoLr, "from the parent Vue component" not from the parent, but to the parent. After user specify them it should be send to parent.

Comment: Ahh, my bad then, to communicate from child to parent you should use events: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication. You can also use `this.$parent` although it's not a recommended pattern.

Comment: In fact to have a more flexible app you need to use vuex and the store pattern https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/

Answer (score 1):

```
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
   props : {
    uNpW:{type:Object}
   }
      template: `
        <div id="auth">
            <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="UserName">User name</label>
                  <input type="username" v-model="uNpW.username" class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" v-model="uNpW.password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>`,
    });
```

```
App = new Vue ({ 
   el: '#app',
  data: 
    {
      topMenuView: "guestmenu",
      contentView: "guestcontent",
      unAndPw:{username: "",password: ""}

    }
})
```

```
in main html
<guest-menu :uNpW=unAndPw> </guest-menu>
```

you dont need emit or any other thing

Answer (score 0):

Follow this very easy instructions:

```
//Parent Component
<InsertForm :formSchema="formSchema" v-on:getFormSchema="setFormSchema"></InsertForm>
<script>
import InsertForm from "./insertForm.vue"; //select file

export default {
components: { InsertForm },

data: () => ({
    formSchema:{
       id:'',
       webUrl:''
    },
}),

methods: {
      setFormSchema(data)
      {
        this.formSchema = data.formSchema;
      }
    }
}
</script>

// From Child Component. That means from insertForm.vue file

<script>

export default {
    props: ["formSchema"],
    data: () => ({

    }),
}
//Where you need
this.$emit("getFormSchema", {'formSchema':{"id":1,"webUrl":"bdprescription.com"}});
</script>
```