# How to open and close a modal within a child component using a prop, vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, components

I currently have the following child component

```
  <Edit
     @fetchInfo="fetchInfo"
     :agencyData="agency"
     :dialogEdit.sync="dialogEdit"
   ></Edit>
```

Which basically contains a modal

initially it is false, so as not to show the modal:

```
data(){
 return {
    dialogEdit: false
 }
}
```

by a method I do:

```
open(){
  this.dialogEdit = true;
}
```

In my `<Edit></Edit>` component I have:

```
<el-dialog title="Editar" :visible.sync="dialogEdit" width="60%">
</el-dialog>
```

and received with prop:

```
 props: ["dialogEdit"],
```

But then when closing the modal from the child component   I receive an error

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
>   overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
>   data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
>   mutated: "dialogEdit"

Comment: can you show the code for closing the modal? make sure you're not changing the value of the prop directly

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574661/avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-since-the-value-will-be-overwritten) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, apparently you are using Element UI.

But, as the error suggests, you are modifying `dialogEdit` directly. When closing the element ui modal by clicking the `X`, `dialogEdit` becomes `false`. You could solve this using computed property, like suggested for example in [this answer](http://Avoid%20mutating%20a%20prop%20directly%20since%20the%20value%20will%20be%20overwritten).

Since you are using Element UI you also have another possibility to solve this. The dialog has the event `before-close` which is fired before the modal is closed. There you can emit the new boolean value for `dialogEdit` to the parent. So keep the `:dialogEdit.sync="dialogEdit"` in child tag and add the `before-close` to the dialog and a function to handle, where you emit the new `false` value:

```html
<el-dialog title="Editar" :before-close="handleClose" ....>
```

JS:

```js
methods: {
  handleClose() {
    this.$emit('update:dialogEdit', false);
  }
},
```

If you have some button in your modal to close the modal, you can add the same function there:

```html
<el-button type="primary" @click="handleClose">Close</el-button>
```

**[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mendeleev-v88vu)**

Answer (score 0):

quite hard to understand your question. you should elaborate more.

is all this in the same file? if in that case you no need to create a `props` as there's already dialogEdit in the `data()` section.
`props` value is never redefined so if this is the cases, just remove the props.

if that's not solved your problem please update your question with better explaination because i just see one file.