# Vue binding parent and child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to binding parent's model to child in Vue.js?

These codes below is works fine. if i fill the input manually, then child's model return it's value to the parent's model.

But the issue is, if the data set from AJAX request in a parent, the input doesn't automatically filled.

Can anyone help me on this?

**Form.vue**

```
<template>
    <form-input v-model="o.name" :fieldModel="o.name" @listenChanges="o.name = $event"/>
    <form-input v-model="o.address" :fieldModel="o.address" @listenChanges="o.address = $event"/>
</template>

<script>
    import FormInput from '../share/FormInput.vue'

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                o: {
                    name: '',
                    address: ''
                }
            }
        },
        components: { 'form-input': FormInput },
        created: function() {
            axios.get('http://api.example.com')
                .then(response => { 
                    this.o.name = response.data.name
                    this.o.address = response.data.address
                })
                .catch(e => { console.log(e) })
        }
    }
</script>
```

**FormInput.vue**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model='fieldModelValue' @input="forceUpper($event, fieldModel)">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['fieldModel'],
        data() {
            return {
                fieldModelValue: ''
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.fieldModelValue = this.fieldModel;
        },
        methods: {
            forceUpper(e, m) {
                const start = e.target.selectionStart;
                e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
                this.fieldModelValue = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
                this.$emit('listenChanges', this.fieldModelValue)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use `v-bind` instead of `v-model`

Comment: in parent template, bind Props=fieldModel. <form-input v-model="o.name" fieldModel="o.name" @listenChanges="o.name = $event"/>

Comment: @Ohgodwhy which v-model should i change?

Comment: @Sphinx it's actually bind, i've update the code

Comment: still not working?

Comment: @Sphinx still not working. the o.name value has been set via ajax, but doesnt show in the field value

Comment: changed data property in child component: data() {
            return {
                fieldModelValue: this.fieldModel;
            }
        },

Comment: `<template>` should contain only one node in order for the render function to work. In your `Form` component you have two nodes, wrap them in another element such as `<form>`.

Comment: Not sure, but: Maybe it's that `this.fieldModelValue = this.fieldModel;` doesn't get called again after the axios call, so even thou the child might have updated `fieldModel`, it's not updating `fieldModelValue`. Maybe instead of mounted, use a watcher on the prop and make the assignment there?

Also: something to consider: v-model already will use @input, so v-model and @input together is weird (wrong?) (reference: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things are more straightforward if you take advantage of [`v-model` in components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

If you put `v-model` on a component, the component should take a prop named `value`, and should emit `input` events to trigger it to update.

I like to make a `computed` to hide the event emitting, and allow me to just `v-model` the `computed` inside my component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    o: {
      name: '',
      address: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    'form-input': {
      template: '#form-input',
      props: ['value'],
      computed: {
        fieldModelValue: {
          get() {
            return this.value;
          },
          set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('input', newValue.toUpperCase());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Simulate axios call
  created: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.o.name = 'the name';
      this.o.address = 'and address';
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Name ({{o.name}})
  <form-input v-model="o.name"></form-input>
  Address ({{o.address}})
  <form-input v-model="o.address"></form-input>
</div>

<template id="form-input">
    <input type="text" v-model='fieldModelValue'>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanations helped me to get rid of [this Vue warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn) without loosing data sync, finally !

Answer (score 0):

The `mounted()` hook is blocking subsequent updates from the parent.

Remove mounted and change v-model to 'fieldModel'

```js
<template>
    <input type="text" :value='fieldModel' @input="forceUpper($event, fieldModel)">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['fieldModel'],
    data() {
      return {
          fieldModelValue: ''
      }
    },
    // mounted: function() {
    //   this.fieldModelValue = this.fieldModel;
    // },
    methods: {
      forceUpper(e, m) {
        const start = e.target.selectionStart;
        e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
        this.fieldModelValue = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
        this.$emit('listenChanges', this.fieldModelValue)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Demo** [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6vlp5ryv03)

Comment: Don't use `v-model`, use `value`. `v-model` is two-way, and you want one-way binding.

Comment: If you are handling the return-value, v-model is not, so it is not doing two-way binding.

Comment: I'm commenting on your code here, specifically this line: `v-model='fieldModel' @input="forceUpper($event, fieldModel)"` 
It should be `:value` rather than `v-model`, because you're handling the `input` events separately.

Comment: both of your answer is hit the goals. btw, RichardMatsen answer give me warning says **Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.**. so i choose Roy answer.

Comment: Fair enough, he has the more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Your specific fix changed the code to use `v-model` on a prop, which is a bad idea. A 5 second update would get rid of bad code in your answer.