# Prop mutating warning in VUE

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I got an vue-warning (which results to as an error on my end coz my code is not working) that says:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "editmode"
```

With it, tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn#) but can't make it work. Below is my work:

```
props:{
    editmode:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
},
methods:{
    toggleM(){
        var editmode = this.editmode;
        editmode = !editmode;
        this.editmode = editmode; 
        if(editmode == false){
            //dothis
        }else{
            //dothat
        }
    },
}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<template>
<div class="ui-table-container-body">
        <div class="ui-table" v-if="Boolean(items.length) || Boolean(Object.keys(items).length)" v-cloak>
            <ui-table-body ref="body" v-model="items"
                :editmode="editmode"
                >
            </ui-table-body>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The line `this.editmode = editmode;` is the one pointed in my console, is there any way I can surpass this?

Comment: Depends, Did you want to change the prop value on the parent that passed down the prop? or just set a local value?

Comment: You can't mutate a prop directly. You must use a `data` variable and `watch` the mutations of your prop to apply it to the data and `watch` the mutations of your data to `$emit` event and mutate your prop in the parent component

Comment: @CUGreen have to change the prop value on the parent that passed down the prop and have to have a copy in local.

Comment: @LeCintas How can I possibly do that? (drunk)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate props from the component itself. See the [One Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) section of the guide. You can use a prop as the initial value, and then keep a value in the `data` section and mutate that:

```
props: {
    editmode: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
},
data () {
    return {
        emode: this.editmode,
    }
},
methods: {
    toggleM () {
        let editmode = this.emode;
        editmode = !editmode;
        this.emode = editmode; 
        if (editmode == false) {
            // dothis
        } else {
            // dothat
        }
    },
}
```

#### Demo

```js
Vue.component('editbox', {
  template: '<div>' +
    '<button @click="toggleM">{{ btext }}</button>' +
    '<input v-if="emode" />' +
    '</div>',
  props: ['editmode'],
  data () {
    return {
      emode: this.editmode,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    btext () {
      return this.emode ? "Text" : "Edit";
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleM() {
        this.emode = !this.emode;
    },
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    mode: true,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <editbox :editmode="mode" />
</div>
```

Comment: you have to refer to `this.emode` (from `data`) in the field `v-if`, not to `editmode`) (the prop).

Comment: What do you mean by that? (drunk)

Comment: it's demonstrated in the demo snippet

Comment: When I added this line `input v-if="emode"`, my table is not displaying anymore :S

Comment: I've updated my question with my template. If you can help me see it. Thanks.

Comment: your template seems that of the parent, hard to tell why you have the problem with `v-if`. Post a minimal but complete example and I'll try to help (maybe in a different question and let me know in a comment). If this solved your doubt about the prop mutation warning, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: All of the answers here solved the mutation problem, but all of it also results different errors after.

Comment: your new errors probably are due to something else. Setup a minimal but reproducible example exhibiting the new errors, e.g. on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue), post a new question with the link and I'll try to help you. Let me know the link to the new question (put it in a comment here maybe).

Comment: Just a qq, why is it that your **demo** code and above the **demo** codes different?

Comment: The first code snippet tries to as similar as possible to your original code , to give you more context, while the demo is simplified and more what I'd do in practice (there is no need for the temporary `editmode` variable, no need for the if, ...)

Comment: You mean with this one : *(there is no need for the temporary editmode variable, no need for the if, ...)* is that I don't have to do this : `if (editmode == false) {
            // dothis
        } else {
            // dothat
        }`?

Comment: yes, exactly, and you need only `this.emode` and not the temporary `editmode`

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `data` variable as a gateway to your `prop`.

In your component, the code code should look like this:

```js
props:{
    editmode:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
},
data: {
  dataEditMode = false
},
watch: {
    'editmode': {
      handler: 'onEditmodeChanged',
      immediate: true,
    },
    'dataEditMode': {
      handler: 'onDataEditModeChanged'
    }
},
methods:{
    toggleM(){
        var editmode = this.dataEditMode;
        editmode = !editmode;
        this.dataEditMode = editmode; 
        if(editmode == false){
            //dothis
        }else{
            //dothat
        }
    },
    onEditmodeChanged (newVal) {
      this.dataEditMode = newVal
    },
    onDataEditModeChanged (newVal) {
      this.$emit('editmodeChanged', newVal)
    }
}
```

and the the inclusion of this component in your parent-component should look like this:

`<my-component-name :editmode="editmode" @editmodeChanged="(e) => { editmode = e }"></my-component-name>`

Comment: no, mutating properties from the component itself should be avoided. This solution also doesn't solve the problem of the parent re-mutating the property. And the warning is still emitted.

Comment: My bad, I just edited the code. It was a mistake: I copied/paste the autor's code

Comment: @LeCintas I can edit now the fields but now throws up an error in my controller.  `"message":"Undefined index: id","status_code":500,......`

Comment: @ramedju this is a different problem now: this is an internal server error. I guess you are sending incomplete datas to your server

Comment: @LeCintas Please see my updated question above on where can I possibly use your suggestions, I'm currently surrounded with cob webs and I don't know already where to proceed.

Comment: The template of your application is not handled by your server/controller. The problem is located in your controller in Laravel. What is the complete error message ?

Comment: @LeCintas Is this a method or should be under `data()` : `data: {
  dataEditMode = false,
},` and this somewhat errors in my compiler.

Comment: While I can appreciate the separation of duties in this solution, I still believe if the dev does not care if the prop is changed by the child component and is only interested in one way communication this should be a design decision. The child can change the prop all day long, I don't care. I'm only interested in letting it know if the parent changes it. To add all of this extra code just to stay within the confines of proper "one way" binding seems like overkill to me. Vue.config.silent option kills those warnings (and all others) if you want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would send back an event to the parent so it could modify its value:

For example (not tested):

**Child Component**

```
props:{
    editmode:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
},
methods:{
    toggleM(){
        var editmode = !this.editmode;
        this.$emit('changeEditMode', editmode);
        if (editmode == false){
            //dothis
        } else {
            //dothat
        }
    },
}
```

**Parent**

```
<child-component @changeEditMode="editModeChanged" :editmode="editmode"></child-component>
```

...

```
methods:{
    editModeChanged(value){
        this.editmode = value
    },
}
```

Comment: Editmode toggles but I can't edit the fields :S . It doesn't even get into the method `editModeChanged`.

Comment: Please see my problem when using the above code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055013/maximum-call-stack-warn-vue