# How to update props in vue component

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to create my own checkbox in Vue. I want to use two icons from fontawesome (lock and unlock). When my checkbox is checked then icon should be locked otherwise unlocked.

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <i @click="statusChanged()" v-if="!checked" class="fas fa-lock-open lock"></i>
      <i @click="statusChanged()" v-if="checked" class="fas fa-lock lock"></i>
   </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Prop } from 'vue/types/options';
export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        checked: {
        type: Boolean as Prop<boolean>,
    },
},
methods: {
    statusChanged() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    },
},
});
```

I received an error:

> Cannot assign to 'checked' because it is a constant or a read-only property

Can you help resolve this issue?

Comment: I've never used Vue with TypeScript but that is probably the equivalent of [Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn)

Comment: Why not use a `data` attribute instead of a prop?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I don't want to use data because this option checked is set from outside the component, from parent

Comment: Just specify a data attribute with a name other than checked, and add a `created` block to the component where you set that data attribute equal to the value of the prop -- did you visit the link in the first comment above?  It suggests this solution.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I did but I have some problems with that approach. I did not change value from parent passed to my child component.

Comment: Hi @Marek! Answers on SO belong in the answer box, rather than edited into the question. I've moved your answer into a [*community wiki* answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67928827). If you instead want to post the answer yourself, just let me know and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 24):

Take a look at the `prop.sync` modifier. It is made for exactly this kind of case where you want to update the parents value but pass it as a property to the child:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

Basically you mark the prop as being `sync`'able:
`<Checkbox :checked.sync="foo"></Checkbox>`

And to update the parent you emit an `update:prop` event from the child:
`this.$emit('update:checked', !this.checked)`

This should get you started for your solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/97rl86n64

Comment: It happens just for me?: '.sync' modifier on 'v-bind' directive is deprecated. Use 'v-model:propName' instead.

Comment: @Doglas that's only true for > 3.0, not for 2.x

Comment: @RickyBoyce https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-model.html#overview

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Answer originally edited into question by OP [@Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851788/marek), copied here by [the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).</sup>

I was able to resolve the problem. Solution was really similar to what [@TommyF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6503654/tommyf) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900308/how-to-update-props-in-vue-component/52916921#52916921).

Here is the solution:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <i v-if="!checked" class="fas fa-lock-open lock" @click="statusChanged()"></i>
    <i v-if="checked" class="fas fa-lock lock" @click="statusChanged()"></i>
</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Prop } from 'vue/types/options';
export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        checked: {
            type: Boolean as Prop<boolean>,
        },
    },
    model: {
        prop: 'checked',
        event: 'click',
    },
    methods: {
        statusChanged() {
            this.$emit('click', !this.checked);
        },
    },
});
</script>
```