# What's the proper way to pass information to form in vue instead of props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have sample code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-text-field
                v-model="device.name"
        />
        <v-text-field
            v-model="device.serial_number"
        />
        <v-btn
            @click="save"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "DeviceDialog",
        methods: {
            save(){
                //axios magic
            },
        },
        props: {
            device: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

The form is available when clicking on the list of devices, and i pass the item with all info as a prop but I heard that I shouldn't do it like that. What's the proper way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could have used `v-for` instead to repeat `v-text-field`

Comment: I head that modifying props is a bad practice, so what's the other way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update props in vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900308/how-to-update-props-in-vue-component)