# How to solve Avoid mutating a prop in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting this error in my console

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.
> Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "catProducts"

Here is my vue component

```
  <template>
    <div>
      <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Product Name</th>
                  <th>Remove</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
              <tr v-for="product in catProducts">
                  <td>
                      {{ product.name }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <button @click="remove(product)" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default{ 
      props: ['category', 'catProducts'],
      data(){
        return {
          
        }
      },
      methods: {
        remove(product){
          axios.delete('/category/products/'+this.category.id+'/'+product.id).then(response => {
            this.catProducts = response.data.products;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

what `response.data.products;` returns is all the products that belong to that category.
Even though my code does what it supposed to do in terms of it deletes the product for that category,
I do still get the `Avoid mutating a prop` error in my console and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Where are you getting the `catProducts` from?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn All you need to do is copy the catProducts prop into a data variable and then you can mutate that.

Comment: Also you shouldn't mutate a prop directly but there are some ways to work around it

Comment: coping prop to data might be one possible fix but I don't think it's always a best practice.

Comment: It completely depends on where are you getting the prop from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here that go wrong:

1. Changing/mutating the prop `catProducts` directly

**Solution**: emit an event like 'deleteProduct' to a parent components so that it can call `axios.delete` and then fetch a refreshed list of products and overwrite a list of products that is passed as a prop to a child component.

2. Returning new product list from HTTP DELETE method.

**Solution**: call `axios.delete` and if it's successful then call `axios.get` to get a list of products and overwrite a list of products that is passed as a prop to a child component.

Answer (score 0):

1. After the delete call finishes

```js
remove(product){
  axios.delete('/category/products/'+this.category.id+'/'+product.id).then(response => {
    this.catProducts = response.data.products;
    }
  );
}
```

Instead of mutating the prop directly emit an update event so you can use sync modifier in the parent component to update the prop.

```js
remove(product){
  axios.delete('/category/products/'+this.category.id+'/'+product.id).then(response => {
    this.$emit("update:catProducts", response.data.products);
    }
  );
}
```

Then in the parent component if `catProducts` is component's state.

```html
<CatProductsRender :catProducts.sync="catProducts" />
```