# How to hide modal from a component in vue?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using laravel 8 with inertia js. I have created a component that is a modal.
It can be called from the parent component without any problem and send the information. The problem is when the modal is hidden, in console it shows:

*Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "modaldeletep"*

If you hide the modal, but the error persists in console..

Button..
@click="close()"

script

```
  props: {
   brandp: {
    type: Object,
    },
   modaldeletep: {
    type: Boolean,
    },
  }......
```

methods....

```
close() {
  this.modaldeletep = false;
},
```

**Component modal:**

```
<ModalDelete :brandp="info" :modaldeletep="statusmodal"></ModalDelete>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn

Comment: You need post the Component definition for *ModalDelete*