# When i want to change prop in the setter "avoid mutating prop error" shows

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, vue-props

After I pass an array as a prop and trying to change prop in the setter (in computed) It shows me the "avoid mutating prop" error.
and here's my code:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        links: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => {
                return [];
            },
            required: true
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
          data: {}
        };
    },
    computed: {
        links_data: {
            get() {
                return this.links
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$emit('update:links', {...this.links = value})
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // Add new link
        addNewLink() {
          axios.post(api, this.data)
              .then(res => { this.links_data = res.data.links })
              .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
        },
        // Post delete
        deleteLink() {
            axios.delete(api)
            .then(res => { this.links_data = res.data.links })
            .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
        },
    }
};
```

any one knows why I get this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I tried this answer but I have to render a list with v-for. When the page initialized it does not show the list which passed to the props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you made wrong in setter,

```
 this.$emit('update:links', {...this.links = value})
```

1. you have used **this.links** in left hand side to assign **value**, i mean you are directly trying to assign **value** into **this.links** so it is the cause of mutation error.
2. you are trying to pass object into **this.links** instead of array though **links props** type is **Array**.

so try to resolve the above 2 issues, then i think it will work fine.

just replace the setter $emit like below,

```
 this.$emit('update:links', [...value])
```

or

```
this.$emit('update:links', value)
```

hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: already updated my post, so change the $emit as like as given in post

Comment: Thanks to you the error disappeared. Now the problem is when I add or delete an item in the array, my changes don't update and show in v-for.

Comment: may be you did not use .sync whenever you used links props in tag. as you know prop is unidirectional so parent to child. but you are trying child to parent. so you have to add .sync in your tag where you have used :links. so now you have to use :links.sync.