# Vue2 Sending Object as prop to component either empty or with properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Say we have two routes: `edit/1` and `edit/new`

The root container (on mount) checks if there is a `this.$route.params.id` and if so, fetches the data from the API and fills the `obj`. Otherwise, the `obj` in question remains empty.

This object is sent to a child component which has something like:

```
<template>
  <input v-model="obj.name">
  <input v-model=obj.email">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    obj {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The issue I'm having right now is that when I send an empty object nothing renders. Would this issue have anything to do with the empty object? As far as I can tell, properties can be added dynamically like this in Vue.

Should you need more information, please ask!

Comment: are you sure that when you send a filled object that works fine?

Comment: Yes when I send a full object it works!

Comment: btw, if you use vuex you won't need to pass about an arbitrary object, imo props should be specific to setting options for the component, everything else like any kind of data like your code should be in the store

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Agreed! Unfortuantely not how this app was designed without the store in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to either declare the prop members in the object, or use `Vue.set` to add new reactive properties from the parent.

```
default: () => ({name:null, email:null})
// or
default: () => { return {name:null, email:null} }
```

or in the parent

```
Vue.set(defaultObjWithoutMembers, 'name', 'foo')
```

Vue2 is not able to detect or track properties that are not part of the original object declaration.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: but `v-model` mutates the prop which is not allowed in vue

Comment: its allowed, but discouraged.  and even so, using :value and @input('$emit'...) to change won't detect new properties.

Comment: I'm using `:obj.sync="obj"` and it works fine if the obj is full

Comment: @StevenSpungin Ok your Vue.set method worked! But, I wanted to add that not all properties required it. Only arrays (in my case). Could you explain why?

Comment: The javascript runtime that Vue2 runs in uses a proxy that can only track what it sees when it initially scans the object.  So using `Vue.set` is the work around, or declaring null or undefined props.  Also note i put your default function in `( )` now to return an object, as stated in Braks post.

Vue3 does not have this issue BTW.

Comment: Keep in mind, certain array functions will also not be reactive unless using Vue.set on the array elements.  This is all documented on Vue's website.  I will put a link in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record

```
default: () => {}
```

Will *not* return an empty object as a default.
The arrow function will return void.
If you're trying to set an empty object as a default use

```
default: () => ({})
```

Anyway as prop mutations are not only discouraged, they're considered an anti-pattern in Vue2 (see [Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn)) you should add a data field that either already declares default values or get's its default from the corresponding prop field

```
props: {
  obj: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({ name: '', email: '' })
  }
}
data() {
  return {
    name: this.obj.name,
    email: this.obj.email,
  }
}
```

Comment: Could we use spread operator here to shallow copy `obj`?

Comment: `data() { return { obj: { ...this.someProp } }; },` should work sure but I can't vouch for it