# What is the best way to pass data from a dropdown list to a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm attempting to pass the selected value from my dropdown list, to my props, but being new at Vue I'm lost as to how to get this my selected value to pass to my prop, I've attempted many different methods but it remains an empty string. What am I missing here?

```
        <template>
          <FormLayout>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column is-4">
                <FormField :for="ff.slug" />
                <FormField :for="ff.name" />
                <select v-model="selected">
                 <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                  <option>A</option>
                  <option>B</option>
                  <option>C</option>
                </select>
               </div> 
    
           export default {
          fullScreen: true,
          name: 'CcRequestForm',
          mixins: [BaseForm],
        
          props: {
             selected: '',

             modelName: {
              default: 'CcRequest',
            }
           },
        
          computed: {
              ...mapGetters(['ccTypesForRequests', 'currentRequesterSlug', 'currentCcRequest']),    ccTypesCollection() {
              return this.ccTypesForRequests.map((x)=>[x.slug, this.t(`cc_types.${x.slug}`)]);
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points that you should consider and implement in your code in order to fix your component.

1. When you're defining props in a child component, you should define its type, using **javascript types** (String, Number, Boolean, Array, Object). So writing `selected: ''` is not the correct way. Use `selected: String` instead. Read the Vue documentation for more detailed information:

   [Prop Types](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types)

   [Prop definitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-definitions-essential)
2. You should know and consider that **mutating a prop in the child component is an anti-pattern**, as their documentation says:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand.

So in your *child component*: use a computed property as your select box value, and emit an event whenever it changes. And in your *parent component*: set a function on selectComponent event emitting, and change the value of `selected` state there. Check the below links for further reading:

[One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

[Implicit parent-child communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Implicit-parent-child-communication-use-with-caution)

[Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn)

I've also implemented the correct code for your better understanding. Open and check the console when you're changing the dropdown list: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-v-model-og0fd?file=/src/App.vue